# Not getting correct JSON format in swift with Alamofire Request

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am doing a get request with Alamofire with parameters and headers, i want a json with correct format but i am not getting it. 
How to handle the response JSON returned from the server?

**My Code**

```
var params: Parameters = [
            "current_facility_id": "*****************",
            "current_user_id": "*******************\",
            "current_date": "\(current_date)"
        ]

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let token = defaults.string(forKey: "token")

        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "token": token!
        ]

        Alamofire.request(opd_appointments_list, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            print("Hurray...... Got the data.... ")

            if let data = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                print(data)
            }
        }
```

**This is printed in my console as a json.result.value.**
[image]

**Response json i am getting with same url in Postman.**

```
{
"tabs": 5,
"REFERRAL": [],
"COMPLETED": [],
"ALL": [
    {
        "state": "doctor",
        "patient_id": "5b4c307ccd29ba3dfe5355cd",
        "display_id": "JAL-OPD-204441",
        "id": "5b4c307ccd29ba3dfe5355de",
        "doctor": "578f0cb0666d673609000018",
        "appointmentdate": "16 Jul,18",
        "borderColor": "#ff0000",
        "appointment_booked_type": "Post OP Patient",
        "backgroundColor": "#ff0000",
        "title": "narender singh",
        "end_time": null,
        "start_time": "11:13 AM",
        "current_user_id": "578f0cb0666d673609000018",
        "with_user": "HgDummyDoc",
        "workflow_id": "5b4c307ccd29ba3dfe5355e0",
        "doctor_ids": [
            "578f0cb0666d673609000018"
        ],
        "time_difference": "1 hr 49 mins",
        "referral": false,
        "referring_doctor": "",
        "dilation_state": null,
        "dilation_state_color": null,
        "dilation_start_time": null,
        "dilation_end_time": null,
        "ophthal_assessment": false,
        "workflow_state": null
    }
],
"MY_QUEUE": [],
"NOT_ARRIVED": []}
```

Comment: check the api using postman that api is returning expected values. If returning expected values, check your requests parameters, headers and url endpoint, does  they okay ? Please update your question according to that. Unless this analysis, your question is unclear that where the problem is.

Comment: do you want json or are you setting response value in model?

Comment: @RatulSharker I am getting the json response correctly in Postman but with same params and header i am getting unexpected formatted data in my console.

Comment: use `JSONEncoding.default` instead of  `URLEncoding.queryString`

Comment: BWA according to your requirement , if you want exact output then remove this line (as? Dictionary<String, Any>) and print your data

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response i got my answer. Actually i am getting Right json response in the console, i was not parsing the NSarray because the value in the "key": "value" is array in all the case except for tabs. :D

Comment: Then your expected json (in the question) was wrong, because it's a dictionary not array.

Comment: @RatulSharker yes its a dictionary but the value in the ["Key": "Value"] for all the keys is of type array except for the "tabs" key. In tabs key value is of type Integer, that's why i was getting NSArray kind of thing in the console. I think i have cleared your doubt.